# Making a URL (folder) Load a file with no redirect

Tags: php, apache

I need to access http://server.com/folder and get a default index.php file with NO REDIRECT , which means I need Apache to deliver http://server.com/folder/index.php when http://server.com/folder is called with no redirect. How can this be done? I see many solutions but some do not seem to work or perhaps are incomplete while other cause a redirect. The client I want to use is Mopira for Scanning and does not respond to the redirect as I suspect others will not as well.

This is Apache2 running on a local Ubuntu server so i is not a server exposed to the Internet

Alternately if I can force http://server.com/filename to load http://server.com/filename.php with no redirects this would also work but redirects do not work!

Comment: Do you mean like the php function require_one()?

Comment: No, I think you mean require_once()? that nothing to do with it . Currently I send a request to (http://IPADDRESS/eSCL/ScannerStatus) and Apache at that IP address answers with a redirect to (http://IPADDRESS/eSCL/ScannerStatus<trailing slash that wil not show here>) but the client making the request does not respond to this redirect . I have tried all kinds of mod rewrites to apend an extension, etc but if they work it is die to a redirect like "Moved Permanently" I can not change the address that the app loos at I can only change the apache server to conform to the request.

Comment: We need to see the apache configuration (for example the one that issues a redirect)